# Fill running task with string as parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

this is a very superficial question, because I have no idea how to solve this problem. I searched alot, but didn't find anything, because I don't know keywords for that I can search.

First, look at this image please:

[image]

I want to create a `statusbar`. In this example I want to set the status "Hello World". For this I created a new task and displayed the string "Hello World". After 5 seconds the status should be cleared. Here is my code for this:

```html
//command to set a new status
//this will be executet from another method
await this.SetStatusMessage("Hello World");

public async Task SetStatusMessage(string pStatusMessage)
{
  await Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
      this.txtStatusMessage.Text = pStatusMessage;  
    });
    
    await Task.Delay(5000);       
    
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        this.txtStatusMessage.Text = "";
    });
  });
}
```

My problem is now, that sometimes I want to set a new status while the old status is still active. For this case the old status should be overwritten and the `await Task.Delay(5000);` should be reset and start counting from 0. After 5000ms without any input inside this task, the output should be cleared.

It would be nice if someone of you can give me some ideas or keyword to search for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Using `CancellationTokenSource` is just one way of doing it.

You can pass a `CancellationTokenSource` to the outer Task, in order to achieve this. [Here](http://binary-studio.com/2015/10/23/task-cancellation-in-c-and-things-you-should-know-about-it/) is a example. You can cancel the current task and and create a new task by calling `SetStatusMessage` again. And before you reset the `Text` check if the task is not cancelled.